# Develop single android app on Mac and Windows using github

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gradle

Is it okay to develop single android app on both OS?

I want to develop Android app using Android Studio on Mac at home and on Windows at work  if i use Github, will i face any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem to work with different OS on the same project.

You have to config the right `.gitignore` file to avoid files with local paths and refs.

It is an example:

```
#Android
gen/
build/
local.properties

# suggestion: also ignore libs/*.properties files for old eclipse project
# can't be added here because multiple libs/ directory can be around in different paths

# Idea or Android Studio
# According to this
# see http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067 and http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1186
# I shouldn't ignore most of this stuff.. but looking at the content I see environment stuffs in it.
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr
.idea
.gradle/
out

# Eclipse
.project
.classpath
.settings
# Eclipse NDK
.cproject

# Mac
.DS_Store

# Generic
*~
.swp
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make sure that all the OS specific metadata (like .trashes) is in .gitignore, but apart from that you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some git client probably `sourceTree` would be the best for versioning control. Apart from that i don't thing there would be any problem.